# C# Ensuring an iterator method finishes gracefully

Tags: c#, iterator, yield-return

I tested this block of code and find that the GetInts method does not exit the method and print "GetInts disconnected" as i would expect, traditionally. I want to write a scroll control that incrementally downloads datarows from the database with yield return, but I am unsure of the correct method.

On the other hand, wrapping the yield return block with using block will guarantee the call on dispose(), but should I go that way?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IteratorPattern
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerator<int> _mIter;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // get an enumerator to enumerate values in the database, at a later time
            _mIter = GetInts(100).GetEnumerator();

            // simulate some scrolling, which will add values to my scroll box
            Scroll(10);

            // suppose this control is now redundant,
            // but this does not disconnect the data source 
            _mIter.Dispose();

            // program ends will connection still open?
            Console.WriteLine("Program End");
        }
        // iterate and cache (not implemented) values
        private static void Scroll(int units)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Scroll()");

            while(units-- != 0 && _mIter.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_mIter.Current);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Scroll() completed");
        }
        // connect to database, yield-return each datarow, and disconnect (hopefully)
        static IEnumerable<int> GetInts(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetInts connected");

            using (var ds = new DataSourceWrapper())
            {
                while (i-- != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("yield {0}", i);
                    yield return i;
                }
            }

            // not called! 
            Console.WriteLine("GetInts disconnected");
        }
    }
    // try using a datasource wrapper to ensure Dispose() is called to disconnect the connection.
    public class DataSourceWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DataSource Disconnected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run it, it *does* disconnect:

```
Scroll()
GetInts connected
yield 99
99
...snip...
yield 90
90
Scroll() completed
DataSource Disconnected
Program End
```

Note that it **would** disconnect **itself** if you were reading to the end of the data; however, you are asking for 100 ints, and scrolling through 10 of them; as fas as the iterator is concerned you've left it hanging 10% in. If you exhaust an iterator block, it cleans up any `using` etc; if you don't exhaust it, it needs to be explicitly disposed. You can illustrate this by changing it to `GetInts(5)` (leaving all other code the same):

```
Scroll()
GetInts connected
yield 4
4
yield 3
3
yield 2
2
yield 1
1
yield 0
0
DataSource Disconnected
GetInts disconnected
Scroll() completed
Program End
```

The reason it doesn't show "GetInts disconnected" otherwise is that ... it never gets there unless you exhaust it! That is what your code says: "print connected; yield `i` items; print disconnected" - it won't print disconnected unless it has first done all the yields. If you use a `finally` though (using the `GetInts(100)` again), then this changes:

```
    static IEnumerable<int> GetInts(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetInts connected");
        try
        {
            using (var ds = new DataSourceWrapper())
            {
                while (i-- != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("yield {0}", i);
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // not called! 
            Console.WriteLine("GetInts disconnected");
        }
    }
```

Then it works:

```
...
yield 90
90
Scroll() completed
DataSource Disconnected
GetInts disconnected
Program End
```

Basically, `finally` is mapped into the `Dispose()` of the iterator.

Additionally, `_mIter` is `IEnumerator<T>`; it explicitly implements `IDisposable`, and you **are responsible** for calling `Dispose()` at some point. Do that, and it will all work. Even with `IEnumerator` (non-generic, not explicitly `IDisposable`) you should follow the same approach as the compiler, and **check** if the enumerator is `IDisposable`, and call `Dispose()` accordingly.

Since you aren't consuming the data in one chunk, you can't use `using`, but you must still dispose it. This might mean making *your* type implement `IDisposable`, and passing along the call. Also, you might want to explicitly dispose and release the enumerator when you reach the end. I can't really change your code to illustrate this, as it doesn't make sense on `static` data, but I would hope that an enumerator would not be `static` on real code anyway.

Comment: I did call _mIter.Dispose() it in the main() method, but not working?

Comment: sorry.. i think I am confusing you guys... it should have also printed "GetInts disconnected", which it didn't. I added the code with using block to for a dispose() on the DataSourceWrapper which i mention in OP.

Comment: ok i got it -- "Basically, finally is mapped into the Dispose() of the iterator" -- but i find it strange that it's to be this way because since yield return can only be in a while/for loop, shoudn't it just break out of the loop and continue the rest of the function?

Comment: @Jake firstly: `yield` does not need to be in a loop **at all**; your code has used a loop, but that is just your code. But even if that were necessary (and it isn't) why would it break out of the loop? Code never just breaks out of the middle of a loop without a good reason. What if you had more `yield`s outside the loop (maybe in a second loop)? Simply; no - that doesn't and can't happen.

Comment: my mistake, I thought yield-return only happens in a loop. Haven't seen one that doesn't afaik. "What if you had more yields outside the loop" is a good point. Many thanks for your explanations!!

Comment: @Jake `IEnumerable<int> GetData() {yield return 42;}` is perfectly valid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6809/discussion-between-jake-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 2):

You claim that it doesn't "disconnect the database connection" - but the code you've shown *does* print out "DataSource disconnected"... so it's working fine as far as I can see.

Yes, you need to make sure that something calls `Dispose` on the iterator - which should normally be done *either* with a `using` statement or (more usually) by iterating over an `IEnumerable` with a `foreach` loop.

You can't guarantee that the iterator block will run to completion itself, but any appropriate `finally` blocks *will* be executed when the iterator is disposed.

EDIT: So if you want to make sure you'll see "GetInts disconnected" you can just put that in a `finally` block:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetInts(int i)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetInts connected");

        using (var ds = new DataSourceWrapper())
        {
            while (i-- != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yield {0}", i);
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetInts disconnected");
    }
}
```

Comment: it should (i hope) print "GetInts disconnected" to show that reliance on the DataSourceWrapper not needed.

Comment: @Jake: Then you need to put that in a `finally` block - it's as simple as that. (See my edit.) Of course, that still relies on the iterator being disposed properly.